# Определение наличия некорректных кадров в сети Ethernet

Tags: сеть, ethernet, пакет

Есть сеть и в ней много трафика. Устройство получает пакеты с некорректной контрольной суммой (см. [Ethernet Frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame), Frame check sequence), а именно хвост пакета забит повторяющимся байтом 0x55 (возможно, это просто заполнение непринятой части самим контроллером ethernet). Вопрос:

- Можно ли определить, что пакеты испорчены в самой сети, а не
     устройством?
- Что с ними происходит, когда они приходят на сетевую карту самого обычного компьютера?
- Доходят ли они до уровня ОС или отбрасываются на месте? Wireshark
     подобные пакеты не видит.
- И, если доходят, можно ли их посмотреть?

Comment: Since the PHY is required  to corrupt receive data on an error, a MAC is not required to use RX_ER.
Видимо, после детекта коллизии на линии, все данные затирались 0x55. Дабы избежать сего, устройство переведено в режип full-duplex и производится проверка crc каждого пакета.

Answer (score 2):

1. Почему вы думаете, что устройство их портит? Байт 0x55 это скорее начало нового фрейма (7 октетов, оканчивающихся октетом SFD - 0xD5). Вполне может быть, что из-за проблем с синхронизацией у вас фреймы сдвинулись.
2. Они отбрасываются
3. Не доходят они до ОС, обычно MAC встроен в чип

Кстати, я вам уже писал, что устройство совершенно не обязано возвращать FCS в исходном виде, так как передача кадра к LLC уже подразумевает корректность фрейма. Так проще считать CRC налету и, соответственно, исправлять ошибки, экономить 4 байта на каждый фрейм.

Comment: 1. Их портит микросхема PHY, подключённая через интерфейс RMII, так как обязана это делать по спецификации до конца активности на линии: http://ebook.pldworld.com/_eBook/TCPIP/RMII/rmii_rev10.pdf (Reduced MII interface), раздел 5.3.3. "To eliminate the requirement for this signal and still meet the requirements for undetected error rate, RXD[1:0] shall replace the decoded data in the receive stream with “01” until the end of carrier activity", откуда 0x55 и вылазит.

CRC не позволяет исправлять =) Но это и не требуется...

Comment: Насчет PHY спорить не буду, вы о ней, видимо, знаете больше. Но CRC умеет исправлять ошибки: 

> CRCs can detect bit errors and correct bits, depending on the polynomial being used. For the common CRC16 or CRC32, they can detect 2 random bits (burst performance is better) and correct 1 bit

[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788570/is-it-possible-to-do-rudimentary-error-correction-with-crc)

Comment: Я это узнал вчера вечером, в общем-то, после интенсивного поиска информации.
После того, как часть пакета (до 30%) затёрли 0x55, это затруднительно =) Да и смысла особого не имеет, как и ресурсов для осуществления ^^'